# Add 3rd Party Controls to ViewModel in decoupled way

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have XAML like this which lets me add in a 3rd Party map control

```
<UserControl x:Class="AssemblyName.Views.CustomMapView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AssemblyName.Views"
             xmlns:ioc="clr-namespace:AssemblyName.Ioc"
             xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/runtime/2013"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             ioc:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
        <esri:MapView x:Name="customMapView">
            <esri:Map x:Name="customMap">
                <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="BaseMap" ServiceUri="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"/>
            </esri:Map>
        </esri:MapView>

</UserControl>
```

All my business logic which happens in the ViewModel, needs to interact with this control and make it do things. Ideally, I would like the the View to have no idea of what type of control it is. I do this all the time with UserControls by making an entry in the XAML like:

```
<ContentControl Name="menuControl" Content="{Binding MenuControl}"/>
```

then the ViewModel can set whatever "Menu Control" object that inherits from ContentControl.

since the `customMapView` doesn't inherit from ContentControl, I can't use the method above that I normally use. It inherits from Control.

Is there a way I can put in a standard `<control/>` and assign my map control to it?

Basically, I just want to interact with this Map object in the ViewModel in the most decoupled way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the [Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx) property description of the ContentControl class :

> Because the Content property is of type Object, there are no
>   restrictions on what you can put in a ContentControl.The Content is
>   displayed by a ContentPresenter, which is in the ControlTemplate of
>   the ContentControl. Every ContentControl type in WPF has a
>   ContentPresenter in its default ControlTemplate

So you can still bind your Content property like you used to :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyDisplayedControl}"/>
```

Comment: That easy, eh? I will try this later tonight

Comment: Nailed it... that was way easier than I thought. Thanks! ContentControl ftw.

Comment: Glad that I could help you

Comment: Yes, Thank you! The more I learn about WPF, the more I realize how powerful it is. Coming from WinForms, I was pretty overwhelmed. Although now I doubt I'll go back to WinForms unless I'm forced to.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just inherit from ContentControl? It obviously has content.

Then Create a template for your control which contains a ContentControl who is bound by

`<ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"/>`

I think thats right anyhow.. i'm on my phone. *Man I love Intellisense..*

Anyhow, Specifically setting the content of a content control to another control seems redundant.

Comment: Hey thanks. I like Lionel's approach. I just did `<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyMapViewControl}"/>`. Reason being is that my View has no concept of what its ViewModel is, and by specifying the ContentControl's content in my ViewModel, I have the freedom to swap out the Map Control and all of its business logic with something else entirely in the ViewModel.